# How can I add a button for a garage door opener?

Tags: garage, garage-door-opener, garage-door

I have the following scheme for my garage door opener:

[image: diagram]

and I want to add a push button to this.

Is it enough to connect a push button just as any other button: GND to scheme's GND and PB to the other pin of the button?

[image: LE:]
<sub>(source: [zwave.com.au](http://zwave.com.au/images/uploads/Garage%20door%20controller.png))</sub>

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes, You can simply connect an additional button between the PB and GND connections. Just make sure that all of the buttons used are momentary types that spring back to an open condition when not in use.

Comment: At this moment I only have 2 remote controls and I would really love a push button.

Comment: This push button: http://www.amazon.com/LiftMaster-Garage-Openers-41A4166-Lighted/dp/B000SRVB76 is a simple button that you push and gets back to initial position or remains pushed?

Comment: Can I test this with a simple wire? Or I need some other components...

Comment: The linked push button is a proper type momentary contact switch. Yes - you can test the button functionality by momentarily touching a wire between PB and GND. Note that the linked button has an internal LED that lights when the garage door opener is plugged in and the button is not pushed. Do not try to use more than one lighted button. If you add a 2nd parallel button it must be a contacts only button without the LED feature. (continued)

Comment: (continued from above) The reason this is important is that if you put two or more lighted switches on one PB terminal the LEDs will load down the PB so it looks like the button is pressed all the time.

Comment: I've bought simple light switch which comes back after pressed and it works. It worked with a simple wire touch. Thanks

Comment: A simple N.O. push button switch in parallel with the existing wall control unit will not work on some of the newer garage door opener units, such as Liftmaster, Chamberlain and Craftsman.  It will just short-circuit the wall control, causing it to lose power and possibly stored settings.  These units communicate digitally with the door opener unit.  You'll either need to modify a battery-powered remote control unit or wire the contacts of a reed relay across the switch contacts of the wall control unit, then wire your additional push button(s) to power the relay coil.